# Difficulty in replicating Ableton Push MIDI CC functions using AudioKit framework

Tags: swift, push, midi, live, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit framework to implement MIDI in one of my hobby projects. In this project, I'm trying to make an app which has navigation buttons (left right up down) and play button (Just like Ableton Push MIDI controller has).

To make them function, I first recorded MIDI data that comes out of Push to map all the keys. I then used MIDI Utility by AudioKit as a starter and sent note values from the app to Ableton Live software, where it successfully triggered sounds. (Kept channel as 0)

Now, I'm trying to replicate the cc functionality of arrow keys which are cc54, cc55, cc62, cc63 and cc85 for Play. When I send this cc MIDI data using MIDI Utility, it send midi data successfully to Ableton (as I can see the light feedback), but it simply does not do what Ableton Push hardware controller would've done.

Am I missing something significant?

I also tested that when a button is pressed value goes to 127, and on button release it goes to 0. Despite of replicating it, it still doesn't work.

This problem is not related to AudioKit at all. But someone who has understanding of how midi channels, sending etc works in Ableton Push might be able to help me.

Comment: this question was asked a little over a year ago. Do you still need help with this? If so, are you running the latest version of Xcode and AudioKit? In AudioKit version `4.9.2`, the `AKMIDIListener` methods arguments have changed: func receivedMIDIController(_ controller: MIDIByte, value: MIDIByte, channel: MIDIChannel, portID: MIDIUniqueID? = nil, offset: MIDITimeStamp = 0)

Answer (score 0):

Is ableton identifying your controller as a push? Ableton has special scripting to deal with various controllers (They use Python, and if you hunt around you might find examples). Thats likely both the problem and the solution. The script is not recognizing your software as a push. However it might be possible to create a new device profile in python that'll give you the flexibility to really get in there and tweak.